# Is there a way to override default template arguments in derived types?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, derived-class

When deriving from a base class with member function templates, is there a valid way to provide different default arguments?

```
class Base {
 public:
    // ...
    template < typename T >
    T myFunction();
}


class Derived : public Base {
 public:
    // ...
    template < typename T = int >
    T myFunction();  // override;  // ???
}


class OtherDerived : public Base {
 public:
    // ...
    template < typename T = float >
    T myFunction();  // override;  // ???          
}
```

This is just for a cleaner syntax (I don't need to override the base function), in order to avoid having to explicit pass the return type when calling `myFunction< int >()` from derived types.

Comment: Regarding `// override;  // ???`.  You can only use `override` on `virtual` functions

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not how to override default template arguments, but the real problem to which you believe the solution involves overriding default template arguments, like this, so that's what you're asking about? This is not how templates and inheritance works in C++, but if you can reveal what the real problem actually is, then a different solution might be possible.

Comment: You mean add a default without redefining the template? No, there is no way.

Comment: Since template member function can't be virtual, you can't override them. What you're doing is not overriding but rather hiding the base-class function template. This will simply not work for standard polymorphism.

Comment: You can only override a virtual function. Template functions cannot be virtual functions, so you cannot override a template function. In the code in the example, the only connection between the three versions of `myFunction` is that the ones in the two derived classes hide the base version.

Comment: why do you think the way you wrote the code would be not valid?

Comment: `override` is commented precisely *because* I know that I can't override function templates.

Comment: I know this code compiles - I was just looking for a cleaner syntax, as I stated in the last phrase of the question.

Comment: You can just create a new templated function and call the base class function. So something like:
`
template <typename T = new_default>
inline T myFunction() { return Base::myFunction<T>(); }
`